# Title attribute to img tag not displaying in Firefox 3.0 Win XP

Tags: html, firefox

I have the following tag on my webpage which I am designing in Firefox 3.0:

`<img src="/path/picture.png" alt="someText" title="Click here!" />`

When I use Internet Explorer 7, the text "Click here!" appears when I hover over my icon. However, Firefox does not display any tooltip when I hover over the image.

I've read that Firefox does not display the text in the alt attribute, but instead uses the title attribute. So I'm confused about why Firefox ignores the text in my title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page and clearing the cache fixed my problem. Now Firefox correctly displays the text of the title attribute.